# Toggle tab content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have a vertical tab that which is working fine. But I am facing one problem here. I need  this tab goes hidden when I click the tab again, something like toggling.

Like if I click tab 2 it opens it's content but I am wanting if I click on the tab 2 again it goes away and become normal. As I am not very good in jQuery I am not finding how to make this or I am not sure if this is possible.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5ezT3/50/)**

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
    $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
    $("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content
    $('#tabs li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
         return       
        }
        else{             
        $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
        $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
        $( $(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The thing you described is not Tabs concept

Comment: Can not be achieve what I am wanting with this ?

Comment: I didn't say so. I just pointed such thing cannot be called "Tabs"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not checking the right item in your if statement: you were looking for the id of your `a` item, not `li`.

See update: http://jsfiddle.net/5ezT3/53/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
    $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
    $("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content
    $('#tabs li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).parent().attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
            $($(this).attr('href')).fadeToggle();
            return;
        }
        else{             
            $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
            $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
            $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
            $( $(this).attr('href')).fadeToggle(); // Show content for current tab
        }
    });
});
```

As mentioned by @urbz, fadeIn/out have been changed to fadeToggle to allow opening and closing several times

Comment: @Nicolas R - Good answer, but it can be improved. Instead of using `$($(this).attr('href')).fadeOut();` and `$($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn();` you should apply jQuerys [`fadeToggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) to enable clicking on the "tab" again to allow it to be opened again. Check updated [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ezT3/53/)

Comment: urbz, you're right, I updated. I would also not have used id attributes to handle this behaviour, but that's the OP sample.

And if he is using jquery UI, I would suggest to take a look at `http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#collapsible`

Comment: I agree, the code can be improved as well as reduced by providing identifiers for the DOM elements that he wants to manipulate by the toggle. But either way, it's working. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Nicolas R's answer is great, but if I click on Tab1 again the corresponding content will not show. May be he missed it in hurry.
Reset your ids also :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
    $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
    $("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content
    $('#tabs li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).parent().attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
            $($(this).attr('href')).fadeOut();
            $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Also Reset id's here.
            return;
        }
        else{             
            $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
            $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
            $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
            $( $(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No need to set the ID if using fadeToggle as mentioned urbz in the comment. But it depends it the OP wants to reset the color of his clicked item also

Comment: Nicolas is right. But as you said it already, it is OP sample. :)